# Getting "Invalid value type" error when trying to execute yarn in my react-rails project

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg, react-rails

I am getting:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Invalid value type 2:0 in /Users/myname/Desktop/work2/reservations_fully_paid/Foggle/yarn.lock".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/myname/Desktop/work2/reservations_fully_paid/Foggle/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

When trying to execute `yarn` in my react-rails project

Comment: Have you tried deleting the yarn.lock file and trying again?

Answer (score 11):

I: Delete the yarn.lock file.

```
rm -f app/yarn.lock
```

II. Run the following command that regenerates the file again.

```
cd app
yarn install
```